# R Package devtools Install Error for HTTR Package

Tags: r, github, httr

I got the following error when trying to install Hadley's HTTR package from Github in R.

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("httr")
Installing github repo(s) httr/master from hadley
Installing httr.zip from https://github.com/hadley/httr/zipball
Installing httr
* checking for file 'C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSGjjYA\hadley-httr-ee0eafb/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'httr':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
Error in if (any(update)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.0/bin/i386/R" CMD build "C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSGjjYA\hadley-httr-ee0eafb" --no-manual --no-vignettes' had status 1
```

Not sure what the issue is on my end.  Here is my version info on Windows 7:

```
$platform
[1] "i386-pc-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "i386"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "i386, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "2"

$minor
[1] "15.0"

$year
[1] "2012"

$month
[1] "03"

$day
[1] "30"

$`svn rev`
[1] "58871"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)"

$nickname
[1] ""
```

UPDATE:  It was suggested that try to install the dev version of devtools.  I got this error:

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("devtools")
Installing github repo(s) devtools/master from hadley
Installing devtools.zip from https://github.com/hadley/devtools/zipball
Installing devtools
* checking for file 'C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsbYABm\hadley-devtools-77011a6/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'devtools':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'devtools_0.8.tar.gz'
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/Users/btibert/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsbYABm/devtools_0.8.tar.gz
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/btibert/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsbYABm/devtools_0.8.tar.gz
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames

Warning: invalid package 'Files/R/R-2.15.0/library'
Error: ERROR: cannot cd to directory 'C:/Program'
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.0/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL C:\Users\btibert\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsbYABm/devtools_0.8.tar.gz --library=C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.0/library' had status 1
```

Comment: File a bug report with Hadley

Comment: Why don't you install from `CRAN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the dev-version of devtools?

```
install_github("devtools")
install_github("httr")
```

Had the same problem recently and this was the fix...

Answer (score -1):

Try this one
install.packages("devtools")

else try this and install the required package
apt-get -y install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev

Comment: Simply based on some of the output included in the question `C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.0/bin/i386/R` I don't think `apt-get` is going to solve any issues.